# Access Denied error in while searching for files

Tags: c#

i get the following error when i try to search for files in c:\ directory..

> Access to the path 'C:\$RECYCLE.BIN\S-1-5-21-3560828095-1020290111-2102031911-500' is denied.

The code im using is:

```
private void button12_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles("C:\\",
      "*.*",
      SearchOption.AllDirectories);

        // Display all the files.
        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(file);
        }

    }
```

`

Answer (score 1):

And this is a problem... how? The recycle bin subdirectories are owned by the individual users on your machine and the account you're running this from is attempting to access some OTHER account's recycle bin.

Comment: right but i am the OWNER of the computer so it shouldn't be a problem my account is ADMIN

Comment: Admin is not the highest privilege level on the system. There's higher levels yet, and that recycle bin is probably owned by one of those super-mega-ultra-admin accounts. Have you tried seeing what the perms/ownership of that directory is?

Comment: Okay, I get it so, how can I skip the files which I don't have access to. Or just check my account's directory?

Comment: If this was VB, I'd just say to slap in an 'on error resume next', but it ain't, and I don't know C#, so... sorry. can't help any more than this.

Comment: @MarcB Could you post the VB Code (if you have it) to fix it because I could convert it to C#

Comment: Don't know VB either. but on error resume next is VB's cure-all for all errors. "Error, what error? I'll just keep walking off this cliff..... *THUD*"