# SearchOption.AllDirectories filter

Tags: c#, filesystems

I am trying to filter out the path `C:\$Recycle.bin` in my file enumeration. How can I do this?

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).OrderBy(p => p).ToList();
```

When I execute the above, I get the error below.

> Additional information: Access to the path 'C:\$Recycle.Bin\S-1-5-21-1600837348-2291285090-976156579-500' is denied.

I also want to calc every file's md5. I have:

```
                    var mainDirectory = new DirectoryInfo("\\");

                    var files = GetDirectories(mainDirectory);
                    List<string> drives = new List<string>();

                    foreach (var file in files)
                    {
                        //Console.WriteLine(file.Name);
                        drives.Add(mainDirectory + file.Name);
                    }

                    MD5 md5 = MD5.Create();

                    foreach (string file in drives)
                    {
                        // hash path
                        string relativePath = file.Substring("\\".Length + 1);
                        byte[] pathBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(relativePath.ToLower());
                        md5.TransformBlock(pathBytes, 0, pathBytes.Length, pathBytes, 0);

                        // hash contents
                        try
                        {
                            byte[] contentBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(file);

                            md5.TransformBlock(contentBytes, 0, contentBytes.Length, contentBytes, 0);
                            md5.TransformFinalBlock(contentBytes, 0, contentBytes.Length);
                        }
                        catch(UnauthorizedAccessException)
                        {
                            continue;
                        }
                        catch 
                        {
                            continue;
                        } 

                        Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(md5.Hash).Replace("-", "").ToLower());
                    }
                    Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: I'm afraid this may be an intractable problem. I would consider it a bug in the framework. :(

Comment: You can't! Only option is to write a recursive function yourself.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access Denied error in while searching for files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10458862/access-denied-error-in-while-searching-for-files)

Comment: You just can't use AllDirectories on the root directory of a drive.  The recycle bin isn't the only directory you don't have access to, even as an administrator.  You'll need to skip the ones whose DirectoryInfo.Attributes have the System flag turned on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following could do it for you, but it is a quick and dirty way, because it does not handle any exceptions. I did not regard any readability and it is not fully tested.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var mainDirectory = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\");
        var files = GetFiles(mainDirectory, ".");
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(file.Name);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static IEnumerable<DirectoryInfo> GetDirectories(DirectoryInfo parentDirectory)
    {
        DirectoryInfo[] childDirectories = null;
        try
        {
            childDirectories = parentDirectory.GetDirectories();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
        yield return parentDirectory;
        if (childDirectories != null)
        {
            foreach (var childDirectory in childDirectories)
            {
                var childDirectories2 = GetDirectories(childDirectory);
                foreach (var childDirectory2 in childDirectories2)
                {
                    yield return childDirectory2;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    static IEnumerable<FileInfo> GetFiles(DirectoryInfo parentDirectory, 
                                          string searchPattern)
    {
        var directories = GetDirectories(parentDirectory);
        foreach (var directory in directories)
        {
            FileInfo[] files = null;
            try
            {
                files = directory.GetFiles(searchPattern);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
            if (files != null)
            {
                foreach (var file in files)
                {
                    yield return file;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: That worked well, but I want to also calculate the md5 of every file.

Comment: @user2216791 you can do that while iterating every file in the `foreach` loop of the `static void Main` example method.

Comment: I saw that, but I think the way I am calculating the md5, it doesn't like the fact that I am not feeding it the full path and instead I am feeding it just the file name. (i think)

Comment: You can just use `file.FullPath`.

Comment: There is no `file.FullPath`, most likely you mean `file.FullName`.

Comment: @MohammadMusavi I probably did mean that :).