# Access is denied to list files and folders in listBox using C#

Tags: c#, file, listbox

How do I fix access is denied at the time of getting a list of files in the directory D?
This Source Code:

```
string[] fileArray = Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\", "*.bak", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
for (i = 0; i < fileArray.Length; i++)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(fileArray[i]);
}
```

Comment: You cannot. You need to have windows level access to file system to run `GetFiles`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SearchOption.AllDirectories filter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19715101/searchoption-alldirectories-filter)

Comment: The problem is that you are using `SearchOption.AllDirectories` from the root of a drive, which nowadays almost inevitably causes System-only folders such as `\$RECYCLE.BIN` to be accessed. See the Dupe above for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

First thing, when you are dealing with any IO related operation use `try..catch` to handle exceptions because IO operations will raise exceptions due to permissions issue. 
You need to do recursive search to get all the accessible directories.
Refer this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34525090/access-to-the-path-d-recycle-bin-s-1-5-21-494745725-312220573-749543506-41600), this will help you more